# Is Type Class + Inline Method undefined?

Tags: scala, typeclass, scala-3

The output of the following code is just `list` (no number gets printed).

```scala
trait TC[A]:
  inline def show(value: A): Unit

object TC:
  given TC[Int] with
    inline def show(value: Int): Unit = println(value)
  given[A:TC]: TC[List[A]] with
    inline def show(value: List[A]): Unit =
      println("list")
      value.foreach(x => summon[TC[A]].show(x))

@main
def main: Unit =
  import TC._
  val value = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
  summon[TC[List[Int]]].show(value)
```

If I remove `inline` then everything will be fine. Am I invoking an undefined behavior?

Comment: I'd say that if this works without `inline`, it's worth opening an issue on Scala's Github

Comment: @GaëlJ Why would it be worth opening an issue if it works without `inline`? It's perfectly fine that way, I think.

Comment: At least to have an explanation of the limitation if the limitation exists and potentially update the documentation accordingly. At first sight there's no reason for such code to not work unless I missed something in the documentation (which is 100% possible).